# java file.delete() returns false but file.exists() returns true

Tags: java, file, delete-file

When I am trying to delete a file which is present in tomcat server conf/Catalina/localhost from java code then file.delete() always returns false. But if I am checking the file by file.exists() function it returns true. I am not getting any exception. Please help us why this is happening. What is the solution for this?

Comment: if file.delete() returns false, then it means it wasnt deleted. So file.exists() will return true. There is nothing wrong

Comment: Check the file permissions.

Comment: The file exists, but cannot be deleted. That's all.

Comment: Are you closing the inputstream

Comment: I got solution for this. Actually there was mistake while creating file. By mistake i forgot to close FileStream. Thanks all for your suggestions.

Comment: Sometimes, you need to be aware of your open InputStream and OutputStream.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> When I am trying to delete a file which is present in tomcat server
>   conf/Catalina/localhost from java code then file.delete() always
>   returns false. But if i am checking the file by file.exists() function
>   it returns true.

Most likely you do not have **permission** for deleting file(s) on Server. Check your permissions.

`f.delete()` returns false it means that it wasn't / could not be deleted and `f.exists()` returns true so file exists but cannot be deleted.

Comment: I have full permission of server. If i am trying to delete same file sometime file got deleted but maximum time not able to delete and the function returns false.

Comment: Is there any other method or library which will help to solve this problem. Because I have requirement to delete the file by using code.

Comment: @vishal so sometimes is deleted, sometimes not. this is very "curious" thing. So try full restart Server also you can check [Apache Commons IO library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) (FileUtils class)

Comment: i already restarted the server so many times. Actually what i am doing is i am creating an xml file in conf/Catalina/localhost dynamically to assign different url to point to same application dynamically. Now by code only i want to delete some xml as required. Then I am getting this problem.

Comment: and how you creating xml? programatically?

Comment: i got solution for it. Actually there was mistake in creating file. By mistake i forgot to close filestream. Thanks for you suggestions.

Comment: @vishal so how i did think. problem was in creating xml files.

Comment: Yes when i was creating xml then i opened file to write xml. But forgot to close. That's why i am not able to delete.

Answer (score 20):

There are any number of reasons why a file cannot be deleted; it may not exist, it may be a non-empty directory, you may not have closed all resources using it, and your program may not have permission to do so, to name a few.

Unfortunately the [`File.delete()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete--) method provides very little information as to why; it's pretty much up to you to poke around and figure it out.  But there's good news; you don't want to use `File` in the first place.

Java 7 introduced the new [`java.nio.file`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) package which is a much more robust file access API. It provides the concept of an abstract [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) and separates concrete operations into the [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class, in particular it provides [`Files.delete()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete-java.nio.file.Path-) which is documented to raise clear exceptions describing the reasons deletion might fail.

Use `Path` and `Files`; you'll be glad you did.

Answer (score 9):

You must close the stream before deleting it.

e.g -

```
fileInputStream.close();
file.delete();
```

Answer (score 4):

If the directory is non-empty then `File.delete()` method will return false without throwing an Error.

You must cleanup the directory before deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

It means that file is existing, but your java process dont have the permission to delete that.That is why delete function is returning false

`Returns:
    true if and only if the file or directory is successfully deleted; false otherwise`

Comment: Then please tell me how to assign permission to java process to delete the file. Because i have to delete the file by code anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

before deleting the file your should close all the file reading and writing connection after 100% file will be deleted 
for example 
                buffedreader.close()
               outputstream.close()

Answer (score 0):

Try temporarily to delete the file with `java.nio.Files.delete`, adding a try/catch block; execute, see what exception is thrown...