# Can't delete files in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to delete all files in a folder:-

```
    import java.io.*;
public class AddService {   
    public static void main(String args[]){
        File folder=new File("inputs");
        File[] listOfFiles=folder.listFiles();
        for(File file:listOfFiles){
            if(file.delete())
                System.out.println("File deleted");
            else
                System.out.println("File not deleted");
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting response "File not deleted" and the file isn't getting deleted. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java file.delete() returns false but file.exists() returns true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336565/java-file-delete-returns-false-but-file-exists-returns-true)

Comment: I figured it out, I was using a FileReader to read contents of the file which I didn't close. Sorry for not providing the entire code.

Answer (score 7):

There are any number of reasons why a file cannot be deleted; it may not exist, it may be a non-empty directory, you may not have closed all resources using it, and your program may not have permission to do so, to name a few.

Unfortunately the [`File.delete()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete--) method provides very little information as to why; it's pretty much up to you to poke around and figure it out.  But there's good news; you don't want to use `File` in the first place.

Java 7 introduced the new [`java.nio.file`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) package which is a much more robust file access API. It provides the concept of an abstract [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) and separates concrete operations into the [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class, in particular it provides [`Files.delete()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete-java.nio.file.Path-) which is documented to raise clear exceptions describing the reasons deletion might fail.

Use `Path` and `Files`; you'll be glad you did.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try giving the full path in this statement: "File folder=new File("inputs");"
2. Use try-catch block and print the exception, if any

Comment: What's wrong with relative path in `File` constructor?

Comment: Your Java class is started up from it's directory. The jvm runs in it's own directory. How would jvm which handles the .delete ever know where "inputs" is located. Guessing it would be bad idea since some other "inputs" might exist and be deleted. So java expects an absolute path and filename

Comment: "So java expects an absolute path and filename" - this is simply not true.  Try printing `new File(".").getAbsolutePath()`; it will print your current working directory.

Comment: @dimo414 Yes were right. It's not absolute filename, but abstract filename. See java source here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/File.java#File.delete%28%29

Comment: And so there is clearly nothing wrong with the relative path OP used.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I was using a FileReader to read contents of the file which I didn't close. Sorry for not providing the entire code

Answer (score 0):

Java library delete function does not delete a directory if its not empty.
Try recursion over that to delete all sub-directories and files.

OR use some external library like apache commons io

```
File file = new File("/your/path/here");
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(file);
```

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
```

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version><!-- check latest version-->
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling Garbage Collector before deleting file.

EDIT: In think that file is being used by other processes while deleting and because of this you can't delete the file you want.

Comment: Hi, can you please [edit] your answer and explain why this would help? The GC deals with memory, not file systems.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing wrong with your code except you should give the full path.

try this : `File folder=new File("C:\\inputs");`

instead of this line : `File folder=new File("inputs");`

Comment: What gives you the impression `inputs` is in the root of `C:`?  It could be anywhere in the filesystem; calling `new File("inputs")` creates a `File` object of the current directory the program is running in.

Comment: @dimo414 I wrote "C:\\inputs" as an example of course. The folder could be anywhere.

Comment: And the correct way to refer to a folder in the current directory named `inputs` is to call `new File("inputs")`.

Answer (score -1):

You have not given the full path for the folder.
Also note to use **forward slash**.

```
try{
        File folder=new File("C:/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/inputs");
        File[] listOfFiles=folder.listFiles();
        for(File file:listOfFiles){
            if(file.delete())
                System.out.println("File deleted");
            else
                System.out.println("File not deleted");
        }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e.printStackTrace());
}
```

Always use **try-catch** for code that contains methods which throws Exceptions.

Comment: `File` handles backslashes just as well as forward slashes (at least on Windows), and `File.delete()` doesn't raise an exception when OP runs their code (and for that matter doesn't raise any checked exceptions at all), it successfully reaches the `else` block.

Comment: @dimo414 AFAIK backslashes produce compilation problems . Also the try-catch is for any NPE's .

Comment: To represent a backslash in a Java string you use `\\ ` to escape it. And `catch (Exception e)` is a terrible way to handle null pointers; if you get NPE's, fix your code, don't catch them. And again, OP's code wasn't triggering any exceptions in the first place.