# file doesn't get deleted inside folder in java

Tags: java, file, nio

I have a requirement of deleting a file which is inside the folder whose name get's generated at run time and parent of that folder also get's generated at runtime. i have information about parent of this folder.i am using the below code. but sometime the folder get's deleted but sometime it return false.

```
   private static void deleteFileFolder(String index_Files) {

        File file = new File(index_Files);
        String str = null;
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            for (File c1 : file.listFiles()) {
                if (c1.isDirectory()) {
                    for (File c2 : c1.listFiles()) {
                        if (c2.isDirectory()) {
                            for (File c3 : c2.listFiles()) {
                                str = c3.getPath();

                                File file1 = new File(str);

                                System.out.println("File exist" + file1.exists());
                                System.out.println("file1.delete()" + file1.delete());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Isnt `c3` already a file. Why cant u do exist and delete check on `c3`?

Comment: firstly i did that. but it was not working so i was trying changing the code

Comment: Create recursive function to delete file. If file is dir then loop over each file and call delete on each else delete the file.

Comment: Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336565/java-file-delete-returns-false-but-file-exists-returns-true

Comment: i am check for that only. i am checking if file is directory then getting list of files and deleting those

Comment: when you say the files generate at runtime, I'd look into two things 1) scheduling logic of file generation and deletion. Looks like u are trying to delete the files before they are generated. coz the logic to delete file looks ok. and 2) permissioning. u might not have permission to delete the file.

Comment: sometime it is work but sometime not so permission is there. and if the file is already present then also sometime it doesn't delete the file

Comment: so u are saying that you have permissions to delete file, the file exists and u still cant delete the file? thats very unlikely. U sure there is just this program that access this file? No other program that runs independently and deletes it? Maybe do a check of `exists()` and in that if loop `delete()` the file.