# Not deleting the Files that are accepting the condition (Recursion)

Tags: java

What is wrong with this code, I want to read all the files recursively on a folder to check if they contain a specific word and to check if they are write writable if they accept this condition I want to delete them.

```
public void del(String text) throws IOException {
    if (UtilityClass.isEmpty(text)) {
        throw new IOException("Teksti null");
    }
    int count = del(folder, text);

    try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C://Users//Admin//Desktop//deletewriteout")) {

        fw.write(
                "Ne totalin u fshine : " + count + " file-a te cilet ishin te shkrushem dhe qe permabin : " + text);
        fw.flush();
    }
}

private int del(File file, String text) throws IOException {
    int counter = 0;
    String line = null;
    File[] fajllat = file.listFiles((File f) -> f.isFile() && f.canRead());
    for (File f : fajllat) {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains(text)) {
                f.delete();
                counter++;
            }

            else if (f.isDirectory()) {
                counter += del(f, text);
            }

        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: Does this code work at all? I doubt it. 1. If the file is a directory you shouldn't try to read it or even open it first. 2, You aren't closing the file *anywhere*, let alone before trying to delete it, so it can never work. 3. As you are only accepting the file if `isFile()` is true, `isDirectory()` can never be true, so you will never recurse.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/38205153/11343720

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the input stream before deleting the file.

```
private int del(File file, String text) throws IOException {
    int counter = 0;
    String line = null;
    File[] fajllat = file.listFiles((File f) -> f.isFile() && f.canRead());
    for (File f : fajllat) {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains(text)) {

                // => Added
                br.close();// We need to close read stream before delete


                f.delete();
                counter++;
            }

            else if (f.isDirectory()) {
                counter += del(f, text);
            }

        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38205153/11343720).

Comment: He needs to close it anyway. This code will leak file descriptors.