# how to delete a java file created from akka streams

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am using akka streams and am following [tutorial](https://davidfrancoeur.com/post/akka-http-multipart-form/). The code is trying to delete the created file but it's not getting deleted. I was unable to know which resource is left opened. `file.delete()` is returning false. the file has the permission of `read`, `write` and `execute`

Here is the example code

```scala
    final case class FileField(fieldName: String, fileNameF: FileInfo ⇒ File)
    
    final case class PartsAndFiles(form: immutable.Map[String, List[String]], files: immutable.Seq[(FileInfo, File)]) {
      final def addForm(fieldName: String, content: String): PartsAndFiles = this.copy(
        form = {
          val existingContent: List[String] = this.form.getOrElse(fieldName, List.empty)
          val newContents: List[String] = content :: existingContent
    
          this.form + (fieldName -> newContents)
        }
      )
      final def addFile(info: FileInfo, file: File): PartsAndFiles = this.copy(
        files = this.files :+ ((info, file))
      )
    }
    object PartsAndFiles {
      val Empty = PartsAndFiles(immutable.Map.empty, immutable.Seq.empty)
    }
    
    def formAndFiles(
        fileFields: immutable.Seq[FileField]
      ): Directive1[PartsAndFiles] = entity(as[Multipart.FormData]).flatMap { formData ⇒
      extractRequestContext.flatMap { ctx ⇒
        implicit val mat = ctx.materializer
        implicit val ec = ctx.executionContext
    
        val uploadingSink =
          Sink.foldAsync[PartsAndFiles, Multipart.FormData.BodyPart](PartsAndFiles.Empty) {
            (acc, part) ⇒
              def discard(p: Multipart.FormData.BodyPart): Future[PartsAndFiles] = {
                p.entity.discardBytes()
                Future.successful(acc)
              }
    
              part.filename.map { fileName ⇒
                fileFields.find(_.fieldName == part.name)
                  .map {
                    case FileField(fieldName, destFn) ⇒
                      val fileInfo = FileInfo(part.name, fileName, part.entity.contentType)
                      val dest = destFn(fileInfo)
    
                      part.entity.dataBytes.runWith(FileIO.toPath(dest.toPath)).map { _ ⇒
                        acc.addFile(fileInfo, dest)
                      }
                  }.getOrElse(discard(part))
              } getOrElse {
                part.entity match {
                  case HttpEntity.Strict(ct, data) if ct.isInstanceOf[ContentType.NonBinary] ⇒
                    val charsetName = ct.asInstanceOf[ContentType.NonBinary].charset.nioCharset.name
                    val partContent = data.decodeString(charsetName)
    
                    Future.successful(acc.addForm(part.name, partContent))
                  case _ ⇒
                    discard(part)
                }
              }
          }
    
        val uploadedF = formData.parts.runWith(uploadingSink)
    
        onSuccess(uploadedF)
      }
    }


    val fileFields = scala.collection.immutable.Seq(FileField("picture", _ => new File("/tmp/uploaded")))
    val routes: Route = formAndFiles(fileFields) {
        case PartsAndFiles(fields, files) =>
          files.foreach(_._2.delete())
          val body = s"""
              |File: ${files.head._2.getAbsolutePath}
              |Form: ${fields}
            """.stripMargin
          complete(OK, body)
      }
```

here

```scala
files.foreach(_._2.delete())
```

is returning false

```
files.foreach(_._2.isExists)
```

is returning true

i want to delete this file how can i do it ?

Comment: Did you try to debug and check if the file actually exists and the the path of the file is correct?

Comment: Perhaps this is not the code but environment issues (especially if you are on windows). See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336565/java-file-delete-returns-false-but-file-exists-returns-true

Comment: i am on ubuntu 20.04 lts

Comment: @Felipe the file exists and the path is correct

Comment: instead of  `files.foreach(_._2.delete())` try `files.foreach(Files.delete(_._2.toPath()))` which according to API docs may give you some meaningful exception as to why deletion failed. In any case I don't think doing any blocking IO operations in routes like that is recommended.